# Using Java PrcoessBuilder to run Python remote file

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a python file (remote) using java Process builder with the following code.

```
 List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
 commands.add("/bin/sh");
 commands.add("-c");
 commands.add("\"python <(curl <remote python file>\"");

 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
 builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

and its giving

> /bin/sh: python <(curl ): No such file or directory

Tried with command interpolation ($ in front of curl and python command is not wrapped around double quotes)

```
 commands.add("/bin/sh");
 commands.add("-c");
 commands.add("python <$(curl <remote python file>)");
```

this is throwing

> ambiguous redirect error

Comment: The interpolated version is missing a closing paren

Comment: I would surmise that it’s trying to execute “python <$(curl <remote python file>” as a single command (not a command as a command with parameters), I would seperate and use “<$(curl <remote python file>” as a seperate command

Comment: my bad on closing parenthesis  (its copy/paste issue)

Comment: Separate command means download file to local and then running python? I am afraid this may not be possible in my case. This is a framework where users provide a string of command  and Java code executes them (any shell command)

Answer (score 0):

Java can do just about everything `curl` can do.  Just download the file with code:

```
URL remotePythonFile = new URL("http://example.com/remotefile.py");
Path localPythonFile = Files.createTempfile(null, ".py");
try (InputStream remoteStream = remotePythonFile.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(remoteStream, localPythonFile,
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

ProcessBuilder builder =
    new ProcessBuilder("python", localPythonFile.toString());
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not an option for us.  The code snippet above is getting dynamic List (commands ) from an external source and this can have any valid shell command.